# Certbox Error pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: requests 2.6.0 has no such extra feature 'security'

Tags: python, ssl-certificate

I get below error when i try to renew the certbot,

```
[root@ip-172-31-24-116 centos]# certbot renew --dry-run
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/bin/certbot", line 5, in <module>
    from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 3007, in <module>
    working_set.require(__requires__)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 728, in require
    needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 631, in resolve
    requirements.extend(dist.requires(req.extras)[::-1])
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pkg_resources.py", line 2497, in requires
    "%s has no such extra feature %r" % (self, ext)
pkg_resources.UnknownExtra: requests 2.6.0 has no such extra feature 'security'
```

Also, my PIP is broken

```
[root@ip-172-31-24-116 centos]# pip
bash: /usr/local/bin/pip: /usr/bin/python3: bad interpreter: No such file or directory
```

It's based on another directory

```
[root@ip-172-31-24-116 centos]# /usr/bin/pip --version
pip 8.1.2 from /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages (python 2.7)
```